# Understanding Haskell Pattern Matching

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

Using pattern matching, define a function:

```
ifThenElse :: Bool -> Int -> Int -> Int
```

which gives its second argument if the condition (the first argument) is True, and the
third argument if the condition is False (for example, `ifThenElse (3 > 5) 7 12` gives
12).

How would I go about writing this?

Here is what I have so far:

```
ifThenElse :: Bool -> Int -> Int -> Int

ifThenElse True x1 y1 = x1

ifThenElse False x1 y1 = y1
```

Comment: What did you try? SO is not a homework solving service.

Comment: I'm using online resources in order to learn Haskell and I'm having trouble even to get the code to run properly when using pattern matching.

Comment: What have you tried? Questions should be about a specific problem, and you should give code.

Comment: Well, then show us what you're doing that's not working, and then we can look at what you're doing wrong. Right now we don't have much to work with, the solution is going to be just 2 very short lines, and there isn't much in terms of concepts we could talk about.

Comment: I have added the code to the description

Comment: It looks like you are trying to pattern match on function application (i.e., match `3` with `x` and `5` with `y` in `(3<5)`. This is not allowed in Haskell. Instead, match on the *result*, that is, either `True` or `False`.

Comment: Hint: you can improve your solution by throwing away arguments you don't care about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a hint.

You can solve your problem using **if-else** statement:

```
ifThenElse :: Bool -> Int -> Int -> Int
ifThenElse p x y = if p then x else y
```

But, `Bool` is enumerated type with only two values. You can match `ifThenElse`'s arguments with `Bool` values and define what to do if function gets `False` or `True`. It's called **pattern-matching**:

```
ifThenElse :: Bool -> Int -> Int -> Int
ifThenElse False = ...
ifThenElse True  = ...
```

And at last, if you use **pattern-matching** and in some case resulting value doesn't depend from particular argument, you can hide that argument using **placeholder**:

```
f :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
f 0 x y = x + y
f 1 _ y = y -- in case of getting `1` function returns just `y`
```